# How to calculate mean of data frame based on value count in columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like following and want to calculate mean of each column but only if the column has enough no. of values entered

```
   ID      val1  val2  val3  val4  val5
   41      190   7.4    67      5    1
   36      118     8    72      5    
   12      149  12.6    74          
   18      313  11.5    62          
   25       12  14.3    56      5    
   28       56  14.9    66           6
   23      299   8.6    65          
   19       99  13.8    59          
    8       19  20.1    61      5    9
```

val4 and val5 have not enough values so I don't want their mean. 
I am trying to achieve this using something like `df[df.isnull().sum() < 5].mean()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for columns, first `:` means all rows and then count `mean`:

```
#if first column is not index
#df = df.set_index('ID')
s = df.loc[:, df.notnull().sum() > 5].mean()
```

What is same with inverted condition:

```
s = df.loc[:, df.isnull().sum() <= 5].mean()
```

---

```
print (dfs
val1    139.444444
val2     12.355556
val3     64.666667
dtype: float64
```

Another solution with [`DataFrame.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) for get number of columns with exclude missing values:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.count() > 5].mean()
print (df)
val1    139.444444
val2     12.355556
val3     64.666667
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do with `dropna` pass the condition with `thresh`

```
df.dropna(thresh = len(df)-5,axis = 1).mean()
```

Comment: @RizaGul you sure ? ummm

Comment: yes, but have you tried it? for me it didn't worked. Perhaps you didn't understand what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to mention < 5 in question

'>5' means if column contains more than 5 nan then calculate mean

so it should be <5

```
df.loc[:,df.isnull().sum()<5].mean()
```